# User access control of ABAP reports

Tags: permissions, abap, roles, user-permissions

There is an ABAP report, which on production system should be protected by access control to avoid an execution by unauthorized person.

What is a proper way to limit and control an access to ABAP report and tables for authorized persons only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comprehensive approach would consist of two parts:

1. A proper configuration of the entire system with limiting the key transactions on a target system, e.g. `SE38` and many others. Usually, performed by the basis team or system owner, based on SAP security guidelines.
2. An implementation of the authorization check inside the report itself. That's a duty of an ABAP-developer.

Below, I'm focusing on a part #2, performed by an ABAP-developer.
To ensure the reliable access control, we need:

- to verify that a person has a permission to the report itself;
- to check if the person has an required access to the tables.

Since in the most of production environment the direct report execution via `SE38` is blocked, we should follow these steps:

1. Create a transaction, e.g. `MY_TCODE`, for the report via `SE93`.
2. Assign the `MY_TCODE` to the report.
3. Add an `AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'S_TCODE'` into the report for the transaction `MY_TCODE`.
4. Add an `AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'S_TABU_NAM'` to the report for the required table, e.g. `MY_TABLE`, according to wanted activity.
5. Add to user profile a role with permission to execute the `MY_TCODE` via `SU01`.

As a result, the authorization logic will behave as follows:

- If you run a `MY_TCODE`, SAP verifies if you have a permission due to step #5.
- If you run a report, then the report will execute an `AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'S_TCODE'` for the specified `MY_TCODE` according to step A.
- If you steps "A" and "B" are OK, then the report will execute an `AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'S_TABU_NAM'` for the required table.

The final ABAP-code:

```
" check the access-right for the tcode
AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'S_TCODE'
ID 'TCD' FIELD 'MY_TCODE'.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE 'Access denied to the TCODE MY_TCODE' TYPE 'E'.
  EXIT.
ENDIF.

" check write permission for the table
AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'S_TABU_NAM'
ID 'ACTVT' FIELD '02'
ID 'TABLE' FIELD 'MY_TABLE'.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE 'Access denied to the table MY_TABLE' TYPE 'E'.
  EXIT.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit access to an entire report you can do so on the transaction level. When you create a transaction you can specify an authorization object, optionally with specified fields as well. Users who are not authorized for this authorization object will be excluded from the report. Make sure users cannot circumvent this by running the report through SE38 or a similar transaction.

Sometimes you will need to program this in, however. For example, you might have a selection field in your report for company code, and you only want to allow certain users to view data for certain company codes. In this case you can use the AUTHORITY-CHECK keyword. Here is an example:

```
  AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'BUKRS_COMP'
    ID 'BUKRS' FIELD lv_bukrs
    ID 'ACTVT'  FIELD '03'. "read access

  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    MESSAGE 'No authorization' TYPE 'E'.
  ENDIF.
```